# bootstrap not binding with dynamically rendered html via erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, view, erb, bootstrap-4

I am working on a Rails app with Bootstrap. In one of my views I make use of 'tabs':

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab" aria-controls="messages">Messages</a>
  </li>

</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home"       role="tabpanel">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane"        id="profile"    role="tabpanel">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane"        id="messages"   role="tabpanel">...</div>
</div>
```

This works fine if its hard coded HTML. When I dynamically add an extra 'li' in "nav-tabs" item:

```
<% if @customer.profiles.present? %>
<% @customer.profiles.each_with_index  do |profile,index| %>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile<%=index%>" role="tab"> profile-<%=index%> </a>
  </li>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

and 'div' in "tab-content" with both a unique number:

```
<% if @customer.profiles.present? %>
    <% @customer.profiles.each  do |profile,index| %>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="profile<%=index%>" role="tabpanel">
          <%= render :partial => 'profiles/homes_pane' , :locals => { :profile => profile}  %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

added in the 'href' and 'id', the tabs are not working anymore.

So it seems that Bootstrap is not binding the javascript to the dynamically generated HTML elements.

Am I doing something wrong or do I need a workaround. Any suggestions are welcome.

best regards,
Martijn

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap doesn't know the difference between dynamically generated as it's a client side process.

It looks like you're missing an each_with_index on your tab content snippet.

If you use your element inspector, I imagine you'll see the index for the second part isn't appearing correctly.

Comment: Thanks! completely overlooked this wrong syntax. It solved the problem.

Comment: great. Glad it helped.